# How to test NiFi custom processor making Rest call (HTTPPost) and check for response status?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to write a test case for one of our NiFi custom processor that makes REST call to external resources (httppost).
How can we test this in NiFi test case.
Thank you.

Comment: How would you write the test in regular Junit?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern would be to make a protected method in your processor that creates the client, and then make a sub-class called TestableMyProcessor that overrides that method and returns a mock instance. In your tests you would use TestableMyProcessor instead of MyProcessor.

Comment: Hi Bryan thanks, I am totally lost. Any working sample? 
I was reading a lot on wiremock to do this type of testing. Haven;t gotten any success.